If $f=h\circ g$, then there's a measurable function $\tilde h$ such that $f=\tilde h\circ g$
Let $X,Y,Z$ be three standard measurable spaces and $f:X\to Z$ and $g:X\to Y$ two measurable functions. Suppose that there's a function $h:Y\to Z$ such that $f=h\circ g$. How can I show that there's a measurable function $\tilde h:Y\to Z$ such that $f=\tilde h \circ g$?

According to Joscha Gillessen's answer to Minimal sufficient statistic: a measurability issue in a well-known theorem that proposition is true and, if I haven't misunderstood, the proposition is a consequence of the following theorem:

Blackwell: Let $(X,\mathcal{A})$ be a standard measurable space and
$\mathcal{A}_0$ a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ generated by a countable
subset of $\mathcal{A}$. Then a subset of $X$ belongs to
$\mathcal{A}_0$ if and only if it belongs to $\mathcal{A}$ and is the
union of a family of atoms of $\mathcal{A}_0$.

However I don't know how to use this theorem to obtain that result.
Note: A measurable space $X$ is said to be standard if there is a polish space $Z$ such that $X$ and $Z$ are isomorphic.

I try to provide a direct proof here using the above-mentioned theorem of Blackwell and Kuratowski's extension theorem.
In the following consider the subspace $W:=g(X) \subseteq Y$ endowed with the subspace-$\sigma$-algebra:
$$\Sigma_W := \{ B \cap W \mid B \in \Sigma_Y  \}.$$
Kuratowski's extension theorem states that every measurable map $ h:W \to Z$ to a standard measurable space $Z$ can be extended to a measurable map $\tilde h:Y \to Z$.
This means that we only need to consider the surjective measurable map $g: X \to W$ and a map $h: W \to Z$ with $h \circ g = f$. We are thus left to show that such an $h$ is measurable.
Since $Y$ is a standard measurable space, $\Sigma_Y$ is countably generated and separated, which implies the same for $\Sigma_W$. So there exists a countable algebra $F$ that separates the points of $W$ such that $\Sigma_W = \sigma(F)$. In particular, the atoms of $\Sigma_W$ are the singletons $\{w\}$ for $w \in W$.
Now consider the two sub-$\sigma$-algebras of $\Sigma_X$:
$$ \Sigma_1 := \sigma(\{ g^{-1}(B) \mid B \in F \}), \qquad
\Sigma_2 := \{ g^{-1}(B) \mid B \subseteq W, g^{-1}(B) \in \Sigma_X \}. $$
Since $g$ is measurable, it is clear that we have the inclusion:
$$\Sigma_1 \subseteq \Sigma_2 \subseteq \Sigma_X.$$
Furthermore, $\Sigma_1$ is countably generated and its atoms are of the form $g^{-1}(w)$ for $w \in W$.
Now Blackwell's theorem also implies the reverse inclusion $\Sigma_2 \subseteq \Sigma_1$. Indeed, if $A = g^{-1}(B) \in \Sigma_2$ with $g^{-1}(B) \in \Sigma_X$ and $B \subseteq W$, then $A = \bigcup_{w \in B} g^{-1}(w)$ and thus $A \in \Sigma_1$ by Blackwell's theorem.
We thus get the equality:
$$\Sigma_1 = \Sigma_2.$$
We now focus on the push-forward $\sigma$-algebras:
$$ g_*\Sigma := \{ B \subseteq W \mid g^{-1}(B) \in \Sigma \}.$$
By the surjectivity of $g$ we always have $g(g^{-1}(B))=B$ for every $B \subseteq W$. We thus get the chain of equalities:
$$ g_*\Sigma_X = g_*\Sigma_2 = g_*\Sigma_1 = \sigma(F)=\Sigma_W. $$
Now let $C \in \Sigma_Z$. By the measurability of $f$ we get:
$$\Sigma_X \ni f^{-1}(C) = g^{-1}(h^{-1}(C)).$$
This shows that:
$$h^{-1}(C) \in g_*\Sigma_X = \Sigma_W,$$
which shows that $h$ is measurable. This concludes the proof.
Edit: A short argument to see Kuratowski's extension theorem is to consider $Z=[0,\infty]$, which one wlog can always assume if $Z$ is a standard measurable space. Then the map $h:W \to Z$ is the limit of simple functions of the form:
$$ \sum_n c_n \cdot 1\!\!1_{B_n \cap W}.$$
Then an extension $\tilde h: Y \to Z$ is just given by taking the same limit of simple functions of the form:
$$ \sum_n c_n \cdot 1\!\!1_{B_n}.$$

Thank you very much! Could you please indicate me some nice books about this subject?

For instance, the book by Kechris 'Classical descriptive set theory', where you can find Kuratowski's extension theorem in Ch. II 12.A Theorem 12.2 and Blackwell's theorem in Ch. II 14.C Exercise 14.16.
The 'Measure Theory' books of Fremlin and Bogachev can also be recommended.

Thanks, typos corrected.
